# Is there a way to make this input number type work? [HTML5]

Tags: html

Very simple, I want to make a button, which on click generates a random number from 0 - x (which I have done), where x is a number input, but the thing is at the moment it just returns NaN.

```js
function randomGen() {
  document.getElementById("numberText").innerHTML = Math.round(Math.random()*amtNum)
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="amtNum">1 To What?</label>
  <input type="number" id="amtNum" name="amtNum" step="1">
</form>
<p id="numberText"></p>
<button id="RandomButton" onclick="randomGen()">Click for your random number</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined the variable `amtNum`. Please add this line at the starting of your script -

```
const amtNum = document.getElementById("amtNum").value;
```

Comment: Then give a green tick on my answer 

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you read form values in modern browsers; it only used to work in Internet Explorer if I recall correctly. You need to use DOM methods, e.g.:

```js
function randomGen() {
  var amtNum = parseInt(document.getElementById("amtNum").value, 10);
  if (!isNaN(amtNum)) {
    document.getElementById("numberText").innerHTML = Math.round(Math.random()*amtNum);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="amtNum">1 To What?</label>
  <input type="number" id="amtNum" name="amtNum" step="1">
</form>
<p id="numberText"></p>
<button id="RandomButton" onclick="randomGen()">Click for your random number</button>
```